# How to use Property Injection with AutoFac?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inversion-of-control, log4net, autofac

In a Console application, I'm using Log4Net and in the Main method I'm getting the logger object. Now, I'd like to make this log object available in all my classes by letting all the classes inherit from a BaseClass which has a ILog property and is supposed to be set by Property Injection rather than Constructor Injection.

I'm using AutoFac IoC container, how to inject my log Object to the Log property of my every class?

What's the best/easiest way to achieve this?

Is there any way to automatically resolve types?

Below is my test application:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static ILog Log;
        static IContainer Container;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                
           InitializeLogger();

           InitializeAutoFac();

            // the below works but could it be done automatically (without specifying the name of each class)?
           Product.Log = Container.Resolve<ILog>();

           // tried below but didn't inject ILog object into the Product
           Container.Resolve<Product>();

           RunTest();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void RunTest()
        {
            var product = new Product();
            product.Do();
        }

        private static void InitializeAutoFac()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.Register(c => Log).As<ILog>();

            builder.RegisterType<Product>().PropertiesAutowired();

            Container = builder.Build();            
        }

        private static void InitializeLogger()
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

            Log = LogManager.GetLogger("LoggerName");
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public static ILog Log { get; set; }

        public void Do()
        {
            // this throws exception because Log is not set   
            Log.Debug("some Debug");  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also create a static instance of logger in each of your classes. That way each logger will automatically have the name of the class, where it was defined.

Comment: Remove `static` out of Ilog in `Product`

Comment: I tried with being instance as well but didn't help.

Comment: You code is working try: `var product = Container.Resolve<Product>()` you can see instance of Ilog inside, I have just debugged

Comment: If you use IoContainer: you can not call `new` to create instance, you have to resolve via Container, so you should change yout method `DoTest`

Comment: I see, thanks! what if I need some classes to be created at runtime later rather than initially? For example, I might be having a ProductFactory class with CreateProduct() method, so my Factory class will be responsible to inject the dependencies then? I see, so I create a factory class and pass all the dependencies of its products then the factory injects them for me later at runtime.

Comment: Should we make our Container object accessible throughout the application then perhaps using a ServiceLocator?

Comment: Logging (almost) never needs to managed by a DI container. Just use log4net directly.

Comment: @default.kramer I see this statement all the time and I disagree. From my experience, logging is a perfect example of something that should be abstracted. Using an implementation like Log4Net directly couples you to that implementation.

Answer (score 27):

Use [Property Injection](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html):

```
builder.Register(c => LogManager.GetLogger("LoggerName"))
       .As<ILog>();

builder.RegisterType<CustomClass>()
       .PropertiesAutowired();
```

Comment: thanks but what/where is the Log class here? I just have the ILog interface I think. The ILog object is retrieved from the LogManager.GetLogger("LoggerName");

Comment: good thanks, I can now see the log object from the container by container.Resolve<ILog>(). but how could I ask AutoFac to resolve ILog automatically wherever it sees it? It doesn't resolve it automatically and throws exception currently when I access the Log property in my CustomClass.

Comment: @TheLight: Could you try to use `PropertiesAutowired`?

Comment: I did. It registers it correctly but doesn't resolve it automatically.

Comment: I have edited again, could you try on `CustomClass` instead of `ILog`

Comment: Registration is different from Resolving. For example, in MVC I'd write DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container)); to resolve my classes. What should I write for a Console app so that the types are resolved?

Comment: @TheLight: afraid I does not understand you clearly, for console: you just resolve at the top layer by calling: `Container.Resolve`

Comment: Yes, if I write CustomClass.Log = Container.Resolve<ILog>(); it will work but is there any way to resolve all types of the assembly automatically rather than manually setting the Log property of every single class? In MVC for example there were resolved automatically by the code I wrote before.

Comment: You can write `container.Resolve<CustomClass>();` it will work and automatically set ILog for you

Comment: @TheLight: did you check it again, I actually make it work on my hand for this answer

Comment: The scary thing with `PropertiesAutowired` however is that it does implicit property injection, which means that any unresolvable dependencies will be skipped. This makes it easy to miss configuration errors and can result in application that fails at runtime.

Answer (score 27):

In my opinion the solution Ninject [created](http://ninject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Injection%20Patterns) is much nicer than the [propertyinjection](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/PropertyInjection) in Autofac. Therefore I created a a custom attribute which is a postsharp aspect which automatically injects my classes:

```
[AutofacResolve]
public IStorageManager StorageManager { get; set; }
```

My aspect:

```
[Serializable]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AutofacResolveAttribute : LocationInterceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnGetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        args.ProceedGetValue();

        if (!args.Location.LocationType.IsInterface) return;

        if ( args.Value != null )
        {
           args.Value = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(args.Location.LocationType);
           args.ProceedSetValue();
        }
    }
}
```

I know the answer on the question is already given but I thought this was a really neat way of solving automatic property injection in Autofac. Maybe it'll be useful to somebody in the future.

Comment: Do you have a solution without postsharp?

Comment: No, but I think you should be able to create a custom attribute yourself by inheriting from System.Attribute and build this functionality yourself.

Comment: In mvvm WPF there is no dependencyResolver available
How could I achieve the same with Postsharp /Autofac/ MVVM please ?

Comment: The check if the location type is an interface should be implemented in `CompileTimeValidate` method of the aspect, so the check leads to a build-time error instead of a run-time error. See http://doc.postsharp.net/aspect-validation.

Comment: Upvoted for creativity. Yes, you're writing less code but tbh this isn't a very loosely coupled solution. The solution is dependent on the DependencyResolver class which is an MVC thing. If the property belongs to a class in the Data layer, this wouldnt work.

Answer (score 15):

Property injection works for **Properties** and not for **Fields**. In your class, Log is a field and not a property and hence it will never get resolved by the Autofac.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Property Injection](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html#property-injection)  (In addition to @cuongle answer).

### Option 1:

```
builder.Register(c => LogManager.GetLogger("LoggerName")).As<ILog>();

builder.RegisterType<Product>()
        .WithProperty("Log", LogManager.GetLogger("LoggerName"));
```

### Option 2:

Or you can add a `SetLog` method to the `Product` class:

```
public class Product
{
    public static ILog Log { get; set; }
    public SetLog(Log log)
    {
        Log = log;
    }
}
```

This way you won't have to call `LogManager.GetLogger("LoggerName")` twice but to use the context of the builder in order to resolve the `Log`.

```
builder.Register(c => LogManager.GetLogger("LoggerName")).As<ILog>();

builder.Register(c => 
    var product = new Product();
    product.SetLog(c.Resolve<Log>());
    return product;
);
```

### Option 3:

Use the [OnActvated](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/events.html#onactivated):

> The OnActivated event is raised once a component is fully constructed.
> Here you can perform application-level tasks that depend on the
> component being fully constructed - these should be rare.

```
builder.RegisterType<Product>()
    .OnActivated((IActivatedEventArgs<Log> e) =>
    {
        var product = e.Context.Resolve<Parent>();
        e.Instance.SetParent(product);
    });
```

---

These options gives more control, and you will not have to worry about @steven comment:

> The scary thing with PropertiesAutowired however is that it does
> implicit property injection, which means that any unresolvable
> dependencies will be skipped. This makes it easy to miss configuration
> errors and can result in application that fails at runtime

Answer (score 3):

I didn't want to use postsharp so I made a quick solution, but it doesn't auto inject. I am new to Autofac, and it should be possible to build on to this solution.

```
[Serializable]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class AutofacResolveAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class AutofactResolver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Injecting objects into properties marked with "AutofacResolve"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">Source object</param>
    public static void InjectProperties(object obj)
    {
        var propertiesToInject = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
             .Where(x => x.CustomAttributes.Any(y => y.AttributeType.Name == nameof(AutofacResolveAttribute))).ToList();

        foreach (var property in propertiesToInject)
        {
            var objectToInject = Autofact.SharedContainer.Resolve(property.PropertyType);
            property.SetValue(obj, objectToInject, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Use it with this call:

```
AutofactResolver.InjectProperties(sourceObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an interface [IPropertySelector](https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/254C76EF.htm) that you can implement and pass the implementaiton via `.PropertiesAutowired(new MyPropertySelector())`. This will allow you to implement any logic you want.