# How can I set up a Postsharp custom attribute for automatic dependency resolving with (or without) autofac on a MVVM/WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, autofac, postsharp

I'm currently setting up a new MVVM WPF project and I would like to use autofac for my viewmodels injection and I think I could create a Postsharp custom attribute to automatically resolve dependencies when this custom attribute is used, like in this example here : [autofac postsharp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23535219/1200072)

Or, Maybe there is a way to accomplish the same just with Postsharp without Autofac ?

this example doesn't work on MVVM WPF because there is no Dependency Resolver like this example (MVC)

so, for now, I just have a fresh bootstrapper :

```
 public class BootStrapper
{
    public IContainer BootStrap()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var container = builder.Build();

        return builder.Build();

    }
}
```

and the mvc custom postsharp attribute example :

```
 [Serializable]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AutofacResolveAttribute : LocationInterceptionAspect
{
public override void OnGetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
{
    args.ProceedGetValue();

    if (!args.Location.LocationType.IsInterface) return;

    if ( args.Value != null )
    {
       args.Value = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(args.Location.LocationType);
       args.ProceedSetValue();
    }
}
```

}

there are some postsharp examples (without autofac) here (that I don't really now how to adapt for my requirements):
[postsharp global composition container](http://doc.postsharp.net/global-service-container)

Does someone know how to achieve this ?

Comment: Doesn't this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23535219/4100001

Comment: @AntonínProcházka I’ve seen this before but it also use dependencyresolver that I don’t have in Wpf mvvm